# Is this a mistake in apple document "Strategies for Handling App State Transitions"

Tags: ios, document

[Document link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html)

> When your app is launched into the background—usually to handle some type of background event—the launch cycle changes slightly to the one shown in Figure 4-2.

Should it be "Background event" at red arrow?
[image]

Comment: It is a little misleading, but what happened to launch the app doesn't really matter.  The main difference they are explaining is in the right-hand box.  `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called immediately after `didFinishLaunching`.  Compare this to figure 4.1 where `didBecomeActive` is called.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, it's really misleading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the green panel is there because your app has to go through "Launch Time" before it can be backgrounded… i.e. it can't be launched immediately to "Background" without the user having launched it at least once.

Or to put it another way… your app has to go through the sequence of events shown in the green "Launch Time" panel.[image: Launch Time sequence of Events]

If you compare 4.1 and 4.2 you can see that the changed events in the "Your Code" panel.  Specifically `applicationDidBeomeActive:` is no longer called and `applicationDidEnterBackground:` replaces it.

Also, once your app is in background (i.e. [UIApplicationState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationstate)`.background`) background Events will only be passed to it if your app declared the relevant requirements for [background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23).

Finally, it's worth pointing out that this is not th[e sequence of events if your app is launched by a URL request](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW13).

Comment: Thank you! It's really misleading. BTW, in what state will an app launch into background? In my mind, the app should be suspended for a long time, or released memory by system, or crash in background. Right?

Comment: In my experience the app crashing in background only happens when it's processing a background event… apps can be unloaded "Terminated" for any number of reasons like the device just needs more space for a user action or foreground app. For example games can be huge memory hogs and unload your app… have a look at [Execution States for apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3)